# Jenkins GitHub connectivity error - Your account is suspended

Tags: github, jenkins, credentials

I am trying to connect to GitHub Enterprise from Jenkins but I am facing a connection issue saying -

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h git@xxx/yyy.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ERROR: Your account is suspended. Please check with your installation administrator.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The funny thing is the account that I am using is able to login to GitHub and is not suspended. I have tried using both SSH and password to no avail. Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services)

Comment: I recall the solution for this problem was something to do with password only. We created fresh public-private keys for connectivity and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a problem with expired SSH keys. I had to regenerate it and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an issue on the GHE operator's side. They changed something and my account started working again. You could also try to change your PAT but that would likely indicate another issue.

See this: [VSTS issues connecting to GHE (HTTP 403)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194939/vsts-issues-connecting-to-ghe-http-403)

Answer (score 0):

I cleared all keys stored in keychain access for github. And then gave my credentials agian to take a pull from the repo.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed **`~/.gitconfig`** and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your previous github SSH KEY and generate a new one.

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C <emailId>`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was expired/bad password stored in my Windows Credentials Manager. Once I deleted it, git asked me authenticate again. It started working again